# How can I clear the cmd window after moving into nashorn mode

Tags: java-8, nashorn

I am trying the Nashorn API of java 8. 
First I went to command prompt and typed jjs which opened the javascript mode of command prompt.

Now I need to clear the code which I wrote. cls does not work. how can I exit from javascript console ? Or clear the data in console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer just after I posted this question. Hope it helps someone.

Just exit the jjs console by using

> quit() or exit(0)

and then use

> cls

Hope it helps.

Comment: quit() or exit(0) will exit from Nashorn (more elegantly)